# how to check null result for mysql query in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

how can i check whether the mysql query result is null or not in shell scripting e.g in 
the following case and in other cases if possible, thanks for your help

```
 value2=`mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute "SELECT AcctualFormat FROM
 meritlist_date wHERE Discipline='phd' AND  FeeSubmissionDate='$value'"`
```

Comment: What do you  mean by the *query* being null?

Comment: Why would you be passing a shell command?

Comment: i mean data retrieved in variable value2 is null or not? how can i check that